About the logical flow of proof of archimedean property
Recently, I have learnt about the archimedean property of real number system. part of the proof I found on textbook is the following. Assume archimedean property is wrong, which there doesn't exist any positive integer $n$ such that $nx>y$, then clearly $y$ is the upper bound of the set $A=\{nx: n \in \mathbb{N_+}\}$, so A has the least upper bounded property(why? Is the set $A$ equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$). But I don't understand why can we assume there exists an element in A that is the least upper bound of A, isn't having upper bound not logically equivalent to having least upper bounded property? Can anyone explain to me about it? I know the set can be one-to-one correspondance to $\mathbb{Q}$ in term of cardinality, but does it help?

$\mathbb R$ has the least upper bound property, and therefore $A$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$ has a least upper bound.

but then $\mathbb{Q}$ is also a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ but it doesn't have a least upper bound

Sorry, I didn't mention that $A$ was bounded. Revise my sentence to say "$\mathbb R$ has the least upper bound property, and therefore $A$ as a bounded-above subset of $\mathbb R$  has a least upper bound."

I understand it intuitively, but not rigorously, how can we ensure this fact in mathematics?

As far as I can tell you are conflating "having a least upper bound" with "having the least upper bound property." The least upper bound property of an ordered set $X$ is the property that every subset $A\subset X$ which has an upper bound $y$ has a least upper bound, say $y_0$. In your case, you have arrived at a state in your proof where you have a set $A$ and an upper bound $y$. So by the definition of the least upper bound property of $\mathbb R$, $A$ has a least upper bound, though it may not lie in $A$.

ok, this perfectly persuade me, A needs not to contain the least upper bound inside, which then by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a least upper bound
